# call stored procedure for each record

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have sql stored procedure which pass and return some values:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMoney]
   @userId int,  
   @month DateTime
AS
BEGIN
  ....
  Select @something
END
```

I want to call GetMoney procedure for each user in users table and use results in sql query. How can i do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole purpose of a RDBMS is that they operate in sets. Instead of going per user process all the users in 1 shot, it will be many times faster

if you really want to go the row based route, load all the users in a cursor and the loop over the cursor and call the proc for each user...but doing that you are using the database like a magnetic tape file...databases operate in SETS use a set based solution

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is better suited to being function than a procedure, but that means you have to define a return type.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMoney]
  @userId int,  
  @month DateTime
  RETURNS 
AS
BEGIN
  ....
  SELECT @result = @something

  RETURN @result
END
```

Then you'd use it like:

```
SELECT dbo.GetMoney(t.userid, t.month)
```

But I want to stress that you're thinking in procedural/OO programming approach in a SET based world, and do not recommend pursuing this.  It won't perform well, so it won't scale as load increases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the procedure for each row it's better to refactor the procedure to user defined function and use [cross apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx). The result will be the same but the code will be easier to read, maintain understand and will perform better.

Answer (score 0):

OR alternatively, you could define your stored proc to take a table variable as an input. THen you can call the proc once sending all your users and it will process all the records you sent it in a set-based fashion. No need for a cursor, no need for a separate process for one record or many records. This of course will only work in SQl Server 2008.